# Let and Get Property in VBA Class

Tags: vba, excel, class, oop, object

I have defined two VBA classes clsEmployee and clsEmployees.

The class clsEmployee contains properties "Name",EmployeeId and DOJ with respective let and get properties for reading and writing the values 
and clsEmployees is defined as below

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Public pEmployees As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pEmployees = New Dictionary
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set pEmployees = Nothing
End Sub



Public Property Get Employee() As Dictionary
    Set Employee = pEmployees
End Property
```

AFAIK Let property is called when we are writing to a object property and Get property is called when we are reading the property of the class object.

But can anyone explain why the Get property of clsEmployees is called when below statement is executed

`objEmployees.Employee.Add objEmployee, objEmployee`

I feel that we are trying to set/write the property of the object of Employees class which should have called the Let property.

Comment: FWIW - Your `Let` code is saying that `Employee` is a `clsEmployee`, while your `Get` code is saying that `Employee` is a `Dictionary` (containing multiple `clsEmployee` objects).  My version of Excel won't allow the code to run due to the inconsistencies, so I'm not sure how you are seeing that it is getting to the `Get` code.  (Although, as Robin Mackenzie shows in their answer, the `Get` code is what **should** be invoked by `objEmployees.Employee`.  `Let` code would only be used in a `Let` statement such as `objEmployees.Employee = objEmployee`.)

Comment: Like YowE3k, I get a compile error when I try to run your code.  However, in your original code, changing `Let` to `Set` seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Get` property is called simply because you referenced it:

```
objEmployees.Employee.anything_here
```

Will call the `Get` routine. You can look at the dots here to help. *First* dot is getting the `Employee` object and *second* dot is then doing the write. So ultimately it is a write operation but you did the get first.

If you want to avoid that then you can use an `AddEmployee` routine:

```
Sub AddEmployee(objEmployee As Employee)
    ' now you can reference the class member
    pEmployees.Add objEmployee, objEmployee
End Sub
```

And call it with `objEmployees.AddEmployee objEmployee`. This seems a bit unnecessary, but the utility of this is becomes more obvious if you want to do validation about which employees are being added e.g. simple check for trapping the issue where same employee is being added a second time - use a `Function` not a `Sub`:

```
Function AddEmployee(objEmployee As Employee) As Boolean
    Dim blnAdded as Boolean
    If Not pEmployees.Exists(objEmployee) Then
        pEmployees.Add objEmployee, objEmployee
        blnAdded = True
    Else
        blnAdded = False
    End if
    AddEmployee = blnAdded
End Function
```

---

In your code, because you've declared pEmployees as `Public` you can actually just reference that from code in a `Module` or whatever:

```
pEmployees.Add objEmployee, objEmployee
```

Comment: `The Get property is called simply because you referenced it` well as per my understanding isn't the statement 'objEmployees.Employee.anything_here` trying to set/write something to an object ?

Comment: @RohitSaluja - The `Let` code is used in a `Let` statement, e.g. `Let x = 5`, or `Let objEmployees.Employee = objEmployee`. (The use of the word `Let` is optional in a `Let` statement, so people usually omit it these days.)

Comment: @RohitSaluja - yes you are writing to the dictionary but first you get the property and then write to it. Look at the number of dots in the statement and think about it that way. Dot 1 gets the object, dot 2 writes to the object. I will update the answer.